# how to find file path where the function resides in solaris

Tags: shell, solaris, ksh

confPlatform

above is the function we are using for configuring the certain conf file in the setup.

```
ksh# type confPlatform
confPlatform is a function
```

how to find the file where it's defined?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Linux...